# Separating line of text into columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, parsing, dataframe, tidyr

I have a dataframe with lines of text that look like the following:

```
         ANTALYA (GB) ch. 1960
    SHOOTIN WAR (USA) ch. 1998
    LORD AT WAR (ARG) ch. 1980
```

The all caps are names, then location in (), color abbreviation, year. Names can be multiple words. 
I want to separate this single block of text into each component: Name, location, color, year. 
I have been fighting with this for several days, and the best working solution I have is to just put every word into separate columns, but it only works if the names are all a certain length... For what I'm doing with the data, I can use it in this form but it just doesn't look nice, you know?

```
sepdf <- df %>% 
           separate(pedigree, into=c("Name1", "Name2", "Loc", "Col", "Year"), 
                    sep=" ", merge=TRUE)
```

I tried just keeping the name by using the "(" as a separator between 2 columns, but I don't think R likes that I'm trying to use a parentheses as a delimiter...

Any suggestions would be much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more complicated pattern matching like yours you can use tidyr's `extract` function which lets you create regex capture groups. Each group is inside a set of parenthesis (`()`):

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, pedigree, into = c("Name", "Loc", "Col", "Year"), 
           regex = "^([A-Z ]+) \\((.*)\\) ([a-z]+\\.) (\\d+)$")
         Name Loc Col Year
1     ANTALYA  GB ch. 1960
2 SHOOTIN WAR USA ch. 1998
3 LORD AT WAR ARG ch. 1980
```

The regex I used here is:

- `^` beginning of the string
- `([A-Z ]+)` first group contains multiple capital letters and spaces
- `\\(` then there's a space and an opening parenthesis (escaped with \)
- `(.*)` the second group is anything in the parenthesis
- `\\)` followed by a closing parenthesis and a space
- `([a-z]+\\.)` third group contains lower case letters and a dot
- `(\\d+)` then a space and the fourth group contains only numbers
- `$` end of the string